# How i can estimate this $10^5\bmod 91$ without doing the calculations of $10^5$? can i use the Euler's theorem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How i can estimate this $10^5\bmod 91$ without doing the calculations of $10^5$? can i use the Euler's theorem or something else theorem?

Comment: You use the word estimate in your question. Do you mean *find* rather than estimate? I estimate the value to be 80 ;)

Comment: $91=7\cdot 13$. You can find $10^5$ mod $7$ and mod $13$, then use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to find it mod $7\cdot 13$.

Comment: $100 \equiv 9 \mod 91$, $90 \equiv -1 \mod 91$, $-10 \equiv -10 \mod 91$, finally $-100 \equiv 82 \mod 91$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I’d use a simple *ad hoc* calculation: $10^2\equiv9\pmod{91}$, so $$10^4\equiv81\equiv-10\pmod{91}\;,$$ and $$10^5\equiv-100\equiv-9\equiv82\pmod{91}\;.$$

Comment: yea , i just thought of this thanks

Comment: @ParisD.R.Y.: You’re welcome.